# nullptr not declared even with C++11 and C++14 enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr, tdm-gcc

I just installed CodeLite and the latest version of the TDM-GCC compiler. It supports both C++11 and C++14. However, when I write a program using `nullptr` it is still telling me that `'nullptr' was not declared in this scope` .

[image]

What else do I have to do in order for `nullptr` to be accepted by the compiler?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe the last option `-std=c99` overrides the other `-std` options. But again, just a guess :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 if I click `Delete` -> `Apply` -> `OK` , and re-open the Build Settings, it is re-applying the `-std=c99` option. So from what I can tell, there is no way to disable that feature

Comment: FWIW, `-std=c99` applies only to C programs and `-std=c++14` applies only to C++ programs. Only one or the other will apply; if you specify both in a single gcc invocation, you'll receive warnings about an option not applying (I don't know if those warnings are transmitted through the GUI.) If the compiler believes that your program is in C, then you won't have access to `nullptr`, obviously.

Comment: @dhaneku.b: What is the filename of your program?

Comment: Create a [MCVE].  This isn't a [MCVE], as otherwise @rici wouldn't have to ask that question.  Someone should be able to do nothing more than install your software and copy/paste and generate *exactly* the same problem as you do.

Comment: @rici my filename is main.cpp

Comment: The error is likely with your IDE. Try command line tools.

Comment: @n.m. my IDE says that c++14 is supported. So I'm not sure how to fix this issue since there doesn't really seem to even be an issue

Comment: What your IDE says seems to bear little relevance. What matters is whether it works. (It apparently does, you simply are not setting it up correctly. The dialog you've posted lists available options, not selected options. You need to configure your project. Look for a cog wheel symbol. There is **no menu entry** for this. The UI of this IDE is a nightmare.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable c++11 for your project. The dialog that you are showing allows you to modify the actual switches that are sent to the compiler for different options (I will explain this later).

Firstly, to enable c++11 for your project, right-click on the project folder in the "Workspace View" (left pane) and select "Settings" (alternatively from the main menu bar Workspace->Open Active Project Settings... or Alt-F7).

Select "Compiler" from the settings list (left side of the dialog) and then click on the ellipses to the right of the "C++ Compiler Options" option.

This will present the "Compiler Options" dialog, here you can check "Enable C++11 features [`-std=c++11`]".

Now, as I mentioned at the start, the dialog you are showing allows you to modify the switches sent to the compiler. Suppose you are using a  compiler that has a switch "`-std=gnu++11`". You could add this switch in the "Build Settings" dialog (the one you show), and then check it in any of your projects that use this build tool.

It is quite complicated, but needs to be to allow the use of different build tools that the IDE author hasn't even heard of.

Comment: With all due respect to @n.m., the project settings dialog is accessible from the main menu, albeit not in an entirely obvious place ("`Workspace`" menu).

Comment: Wait, the tag that represents "Enable C++11" is *named* `-std=c++11`, which is also the default value?  That is ... special.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure what you mean by "tag" and "default value"? `-std=c++11` is the switch that is added to the compiler command line if you check "Enable C++11". It is not checked by default.